# Can a non optional variable be nil in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Can I create a normal variable in Swift (I mean a non-optional) and assign a `nil` value to it or later during the app lifecycle, let it be `nil`?

It confuses me, since it's a little strange compared to traditionally strong programming languages, like Java and C#.

Comment: No, that is the whole point of optionals. The entire purpose of their existence is because of this. It helps in so many ways. In fact, that it is one of the biggest things about swift. Read any book on swift and it will explain (in the first few pages) that swift doesn't allow nil. Now add the "?" and work with it. It's really not that difficult.

Comment: @user481960 you are missing the point completely. Again, just read the intro to swift book. At a VERY basic level. What happens if you create a dictionary with a nil value in Obj-C? It will crash at runtime. What happens if you do the same in Swift? It won't compile. Optionals adds a level of safety to the compiler to make sure that you check that a value isn't "nil" before actually using it.

Comment: Why was this closed with the reason "this question does not appear to be about programming"? It's clearly about programming, and it's a valid question for someone who is reading Swift tutorials without immediate access to Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you cannot set a non-optional to nil, although this seems like a burden at first, you gain a lot of safety and readability by giving away a tiny bit of flexibility. Once you get used to it, you will appreciate it more and more.

Comment: you are not giving away flexibility, you just have to think a bit about what you expect from your variables.

Comment: @Sulthan Agree %100, flexibility here was used as the ability to change, assign things without worrying about types.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not possible by design. This excerpt from the documentation explains why:

> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the absence of a valid object.” However, this only works for objects—it doesn’t work for structures, basic C types, or enumeration values. For these types, Objective-C methods typically return a special value (such as NSNotFound) to indicate the absence of a value. This approach assumes that the method’s caller knows there is a special value to test against and remembers to check for it. Swift’s optionals let you indicate the absence of a value for any type at all, without the need for special constants.

You are describing optionals as a bad thing, whereas is one of the features I appreciate more in the language, because it prevents most of the null pointer exception bugs.

Another advantage is that when a function can return a non-value (nil for reference types in objective C, -1 for integers, etc.), you don't have to choose a value from the spectrum of possible values that a variable of a certain type can have. Not mentioning that it's a convention that both the caller and the function/method must follow.

Last, if you are using too many question and exclamation marks in your code, then you should think about whether or not optionals are really appropriate for the problem (thanks **@David** for the hint), or taking advantage of optional binding more frequently in all cases where optionals are really needed.

Suggested reading: [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483)

**Addendum**

Hint: I've frequently seen uses of optionals in cases where a variable is declared, but cannot be initialized contextually. Non optional mutable variables are not required to be declared and initialized in the same line - deferred initialization is allowed, provided that the variable is not used before its initialization. For example:

```
var x: Int // Variable declared here

for var counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter {
    println(counter)
}

var array = [1, 2, 3]

// ... more lines of code NOT using the x variable

x = 5 // Variable initialized here

print(x)
```

Hopefully this feature will let you remove several optionals from your code...

Comment: "then you should think about taking advantage of optional binding more frequently" should be "then you should think about whether or not optionals are really appropriate for the problem"

Comment: Agreed. The comment "I just can't believe that the language forces me to put the question mark symbol to almost all the variables I will need to create" suggests a design problem. Most variables should not need to be optional. IBOutlets are the exception where there are lots of optionals required because of how view loading works, but most variables should not encounter this.

Comment: Thanks @David for the suggestion - changed my answer to reflect that, and added a section about a less known feature: deferred initialization

Comment: This is wrong, it can with bridged APIs from Objective-C. I'm looking at a but right now via "Printing description of viewController:
(UIViewController) viewController = <uninitialized>
(lldb) "

Answer (score 4):

> Can I create a normal variable in SWIFT (I mean a non Optional) and assign a nil value to it or later during the app lifecycle, let it be nil.

No.

This is easily testable in the playground:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

str = nil
```

The second line will get this error:

> Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

You might want to read more about [Swift Literal Convertibles](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) and [see an example of how to use it](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/using-equatable-and-nilliteralconvertible-to-re-implement-optionals-in-swift-part-2/).